# Finding the parametric form of a standard equation

Tags: calculus, parametric

I need to find the parametric form of $3x - 2y + 10 = 0$.

I found that the parametric form for this equation could be :

\begin{align}x &= t\\
y &= 5 + \frac{3}{2} t
\end{align}

*I did this by making $x = t$ and then solving for $y$*

However, there are two other parametric forms that I don't know how to get to, could you please help me figure out how to get to them. They are:

\begin{align}
(1)\qquad x &= 2t\quad \text{   and   }\quad y = 5 + 3t \\
(2)\qquad x &= 3t\quad \text{   and   } \quad y = 5 + \frac{9}{2}t
\end{align}

Any help with be greatly appreciated

Comment: Look at your parametrization.  Let $t\mapsto 2t$, then you get $(1)$.  Let $t\mapsto 3t$ gets you $(2)$.  Basically you can plug in *any* nonzero constant times $t$ instead of just $t$ and get another one of the infinite number of parametrizations of this line.

Answer (score 1):

Treat $x$ as free variable and solve for $y$ we get $y=(-3x-10)/2$, now you can let $x$ be whatever you like and get the corresponding $y$.

Comment: for your problem, generally we can let $x = at$ then $y=(-3at-10)/2$

Answer (score 1):

the parametric equation for line in space
$$\frac{x-x_0}{v_x}=\frac{y-y_0}{v_y}=\frac{z-z_0}{v_z}=t$$

in plane
$$\frac{x-x_0}{v_x}=\frac{y-y_0}{v_y}=t$$

the line in question is 
$$y=\frac{3}{2}x+5$$

now we can create a vector parallel to the line in many ways so that $(v_y/v_x=3/2)$

$$v=i+\frac{3}{2}j$$

or
$$v=2i+3j$$
or $$v=3i+\frac{9}{2}j$$

now we wiil find the parametric equation if the $v=i+\frac{3}{2}j$

select a point on line (0,5)
$$\frac{x-x_0}{v_x}=\frac{y-y_0}{v_y}=t$$
$$\frac{x-0}{1}=t$$
hence 
$$x=t$$
$$\frac{y-5}{3/2}=t$$
hence 
$$y=3/2t+5$$

you can get the other parametric equation by select another form of vector